# php - Convert String To Date

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert given string in format `1899-12-30 19:00:00.000` to date using this function:

```
$startDate = strtotime("1899-12-30 19:00:00.000");
```

but as a result I get a wrong date, e.g.

```
30.10.2008 00:00:00
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's $array? Should `[i]` be `[$i]`?

Comment: This is incidentally just outside the range php can deal with these ancient functions. Why 1899 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u', '1899-12-30 19:00:00.000', new DateTimeZone( 'America/New_York'));
echo $date->getTimestamp() . ' ' . $date->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Note that this will be a negative value since it's before Jan 1st, 1970. The above code [outputs](http://viper-7.com/2wp5hI):

```
-2209093200 1899-12-30 19:00:00
```

Make sure you set the correct timezone in the constructor to `DateTimeZone` (or you can omit it to leave it as default).

Answer (score 3):

if you are using PHP 5 >= 5.3.0 you can use [`date_parse_from_format`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/date_parse_from_format) function like this:

```
$date = "1899-12-30 19:00:00.000";
$dateObj = date_parse_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s.000",$date);
```

Source : [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php)

Comment: I don't believe your format string is correct - It [does not return the correct results](http://viper-7.com/xYsS2L) in my test.

Answer (score 1):

The date `1899-12-30 19:00:00.000` is represented by the UNIX timestamp `-2209096800`, which is just outside the range of a 32 bit signed integer. On a 64 bit PHP system it will work, on a 32 bit system you'll run into problems.

Use the `DateTime` class to represent such dates, it can handle it.